# In AWS using the Management Console I can not make a file public

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to use the example in "Amazon Web Services for Dummies".  I have created a bucket and put a file into the bucket, but the system will not let me change the permission to public.  When I attempt to do so, it gives me the error message "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against out published schema".  I have no XML.  I am just using the Management Console

Answer (score 0):

Internally they do this via the policy XML. I am not sure... Can you reload the browser page and try - suspecting some change to policy XML and is already cached in the UI.